# My REST API runs properly with POSTMAN but cannot handle requests when called from frontend server/client server

Tags: javascript, reactjs, node.js, postman

This is the response from server, when I send status code of 404 with message ,it doesn't show the message at client side:

[image]

I am working of simple user authentication/ registration app using MERN stack.
Following code works fine with postman but when called from client side gives error 400 bad-request even if I've validated all the frontend data at server side.
Also, headers for authentication has been added.

This is ReactJs code for signup and login .
Signup -

```
import React,{useState} from 'react';
import { makeStyles,createMuiTheme, MuiThemeProvider } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import Paper from '@material-ui/core/Paper';
import TextField from '@material-ui/core/TextField';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button'
import { Typography} from "@material-ui/core";

import axios from 'axios';
const API_URL = "http://localhost:2000/"

const styles = {
    button: {
        margin: 15,
        color: '#AC3B61',
        background: '#ffffff',
        fontWeight: 'bold',
    },
    floatingLabelFocusStyle: {
        color: "#F9A257"
    },
};

const theme = createMuiTheme({
    palette: {
        primary: {
            main: '#EDF5E1'
        },
        secondary: {
            main: '#EDF5E1'
        },
    }
})


const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
    root: {
        display: 'flex',
        flexGrow: 1,
        justifyContent: 'center',

    },

    control: {
        padding: theme.spacing(2),
        width: theme.spacing(50),
        height: theme.spacing(50),
        marginTop: theme.spacing(5),
        background: '#AC3B61',
        color: '#ffffff ',
        height: 500,
        borderRadius:"8%"
    },
}));

const SignUp = (props) => {
    const classes = useStyles();
    const [state,setState]=useState({
        firstname:"",
        lastname:"",
        email:"",
        password:"",
        con_password:""
    });
    const handleChange=(e)=>{
        setState({
            ...state,[e.target.id]:e.target.value
        })
        
    }
    const handleSubmit=(e)=>{
        const profile={}
        profile.firstname = state.firstname;
        profile.lastname = state.lastname;
        profile.email = state.email;
        profile.password = state.password;
        profile.con_password = state.con_password;
        
        axios.post(`${API_URL}register/profile`,profile,{
            headers:{
                
                    Accept:"application/json",
                    "Content-Type":"application/json"
                
            }
        })
        .then((res)=>console.log(res.status))
        .catch((err)=>console.log(err));
    }
    return ( 
        <div className={classes.root}>
      <MuiThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit} autoComplete="off">
      <Paper variant="standard" className={classes.control}  elevation={15}>
     
      <Typography variant="h4" gutterBottom>
          Sign-Up
      </Typography>
      <TextField id="firstname" label="First Name" variant="standard" onChange={handleChange} required={true}/>
        <br/><br/>
        <TextField id="lastname" label="Last Name" variant="standard" onChange={handleChange} required={true}/>
        <br/><br/>
       <TextField id="email" label="Email" variant="standard" type="email" onChange={handleChange} required={true}/>
        <br/><br/>
        <TextField id="password" label="Password" variant="standard" type="password" onChange={handleChange} required={true}/>
        <br/><br/>
        <TextField id="con_password" label="Confirm-Password" variant="standard" type="password" onChange={handleChange} required={true}/>
        <br/><br/>
        <Button 
        onClick={handleSubmit}
        style={styles.button}>Submit</Button>
        
      </Paper>
      </form>
     </MuiThemeProvider>
      
    </div>
     );
}
 
export default SignUp;
```

Login -

```
import React,{useState} from 'react';
import { makeStyles,createMuiTheme, MuiThemeProvider } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import Paper from '@material-ui/core/Paper';
import TextField from '@material-ui/core/TextField';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button'
import { Typography} from "@material-ui/core";

import axios from 'axios';
const API_URL = "http://localhost:2000/"

const styles = {
    button: {
        margin: 15,
        color: '#AC3B61',
        background: '#ffffff',
        fontWeight: 'bold',
    },
    floatingLabelFocusStyle: {
        color: "#F9A257"
    },
};

const theme = createMuiTheme({
    palette: {
        primary: {
            main: '#EDF5E1'
        },
        secondary: {
            main: '#EDF5E1'
        },
    }
})

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
    root: {
        display: 'flex',
        flexGrow: 1,
        justifyContent: 'center',

    },

    control: {
        padding: theme.spacing(2),
        width: theme.spacing(50),
        height: theme.spacing(50),
        marginTop: theme.spacing(5),
        background: '#AC3B61',
        color: '#ffffff ',
        height: 300,
        borderRadius:"8%"
    },
}));

const LogIn = (props) => {


    const classes = useStyles();
    const [state, setState] = useState({
        email:" ",
        password:" "
    });
    

    const handleChange = (e) =>{
        setState({
            ...state,[e.target.id]:e.target.value
        });
        
    }
    const handleSubmit=(e)=>{
        e.preventDefault();
        let profile={}
        profile.email = state.email;
        profile.password = state.password;
        
        axios.post(`${API_URL}login/profile`,profile,{
            headers:{
                Accept:"application/json",
                    "Content-Type":"application/json"
            }
            
        })
        .then((res)=>{
            console.log(res.status)
            
            props.history.push('/dashboard')
        })
        .catch(err=>console.log(err));

        
    }
        
        
    return ( 
        <div className={classes.root}>
      <MuiThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit} autoComplete="off">
      <Paper variant="outlined" className={classes.control}  elevation={15}>
      <Typography variant="h4" gutterBottom>
          Log-In
      </Typography>
      
       <TextField id="email" label="Email" variant="standard" type="email"
           onChange={handleChange}
           required={true}
       />
        <br/><br/>
        <TextField id="password" label="Password" variant="standard" type="password"
             onChange={handleChange}
             required={true}
        />
        <br/><br/>
        
        <Button 
        onClick={handleSubmit}
        style={styles.button}>Submit</Button>
      </Paper>
      </form>
     </MuiThemeProvider>
      
    </div>
     );
}
 
export default LogIn;
```

This is the backend server -

index.js

```
const express = require('express');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Router = require('./routes/Router');
const mongoURI = require('./config/Keys').mongoURI;
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const cors = require('cors');

//initiated app()
const app = express();

//middleware for database / mongodB atlas 
try {
    mongoose.connect( mongoURI, {useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true}, () =>
    console.log('connected to the database successfully'));    
    }catch (error) { 
    console.log("could not connect");    
    }
//global promise overriding
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;

//bodypaerser middleware
app.use(bodyParser.json());


//cors middleware
app.use(cors());

//handling requests middleware
app.use('/',Router);



//error middleware
app.use((err,req,res,next)=>{
    //console.log(err.message);
    res.status(422).send({
        err:err.message
    })
});

const port = 2000 || process.env.port;
app.listen(port,()=>{
    console.log(`connected to the port ${port} successfully`);
});
```

and this is the rest API -

```
const express = require('express');
const Router = express.Router();
const ProfileModel = require('../models/profilemodel');
const bcrypt = require("bcryptjs");
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
const { RegisterValidator,LoginValidator } = require('../validator/ProfileValidator');
const secrete = require('../config/Keys').secrete;


//handling cors errors
Router.use((req,res,next)=>{
    res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin","*");
    res.setHeader(
        "Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
        "Origin,X-Requested-With,Content-Tpe,Accept,Authorization"
    );
   res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods','GET,POST');
        //res.status(200).json({msg:"preflight request was made"});
    
        if (req.method === 'OPTIONS') {
            return res.sendStatus(200); // to deal with chrome sending an extra options request
          }
    next();
})



//register request handler
Router.post('/register/profile',(req,res,next)=>{
    console.log('register req was made');

    //validating registration
    const {msg,isValid} = RegisterValidator(req.body);
    if(!isValid)
    {
        return res.status(404).json({msg:msg});
    }
    ProfileModel.findOne({email:req.body.email})
    .then((profile)=>{
        if(profile)
        {
           return  res.status(401).json({msg:'user already exist'});
        }
       
        const newProfile = new ProfileModel({
            firstname:req.body.firstname,
            lastname:req.body.lastname,
            email:req.body.email,
            password:req.body.password
            
        })

         //hash the passwords before saving to database
         bcrypt.genSalt(10,(err,salt)=>{
            bcrypt.hash(newProfile.password,salt,(err,hash)=>{
                if(err)
                {
                    throw err;
                }
               newProfile.password = hash;
               newProfile.save()
               .then((user)=>{

                   //generatung a token
                    const token = jwt.sign({id:user._id},secrete,{
                    expiresIn:86400 //24 hrs in seconds
                });

               res.status(200).send({auth:true,token});
                })
               .catch(err => console.log(err));
            });
        });
    })
});



//login req handler
Router.post('/login/profile',(req,res,next)=>{
    console.log('login req was made');

    //validating email
    const {msg,isValid} = LoginValidator(req.body);

    if(!isValid)
    {
        return res.status(404).json({msg:msg});
    }
    const email = req.body.email;
    const password = req.body.password;
    ProfileModel.findOne({email})
    .then((user)=>{
        if(!user)
        {
          return   res.status(404).json({emailnotfound:'user doe not exist'})
        }
        
        //compare passwords
        bcrypt.compare(password,user.password)
        .then((isMatch)=>{
            if(!isMatch)
            {
               return res.status(400).json({incorrectpassword:'please enter the correct password'})
            }
            
                const token = jwt.sign({id:user._id},secrete,{
                expiresIn:86400 //24 hrs

            });
           return res.status(200).send({auth:true,token});
        })
        .catch((err)=>console.log(err));
    })
    .catch((err)=>console.log(err));
    
});



//sending the token to client
Router.get('/verifytoken',(req,res)=>{
    const token = req.headers['token'];
    //console.log(req.headers);
    if(!token) return res.status(401).send({auth:false,token:'no token'});
    
    jwt.verify(token,secrete,(err,decoded)=>{
        if(err) return res.status(500).send({auth:false,token:'failed to authenticate'});

       // res.status(200).send(decoded);

       ProfileModel.findById(decoded.id,{password:0})  //projection
       .then((user)=>{
           if(!user) return res.status(401).send("'no user found");
           
           return res.status(201).send(user);
       })
    });
})


module.exports = Router;
```

Answer (score -1):

```
 axios.post(`${API_URL}login/profile`,JSON.stringify(profile),{
        headers:{
            Accept:"application/json",
                "Content-Type":"application/json"
        }
        
    })
```

Please try to wrap the data you post with `JSON.stringify()`

Comment: Error : request failed with status code 400. But , at server side i can see the request logged.

Comment: I've added the link of screenshot in the question .